# Symmetry axis is off center when joining

Tags: modeling, coordinates, axis

I am new to blender and still learning to navigate the interface. I am working on this model and my axis went off center after I joined the parts of the model. Now I can not work on the model symmetrically. Please help where you can. Thank you.

Comment: You joined two objects using ctrl+J right? Can you add some image too plz?

Comment: In Object mode right click >Origin to Geometry? If the origin's orientation is bad you can fix it as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of selection matters. The origin of the object after joining depends upon which object you had selected at the very last.

I will show you by an example:

Here I selected Cube1 first and then Cube2. After that I joined then with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>
[image]
As you can see, the origin of this joined object is the same as he origin of Cube2

Now I selected Cube2 first and in the end I selected Cube1. After joining:
[image]
The origin is now the same as Cube1

This applies to multiple objects as well.
[image]
**Basically, the last object which you selected matters.**

Comment: Technically true, but the core issue is the origin. Treat the disease, not the symptoms.

Comment: @L0Lock I don't understand what you are saying. Most probably he joined the objects in the wrong order which is why the axis is now off center. If he just seperates the and rejoins them in the correct way, the porblem will be solved, right?

Comment: "*If he just seperates the and rejoins them in the correct way, the porblem will be solved, right?*" No because separating meshes into new objects will give them all the same origin as the object you separated them from. Unless the user have a save from before joining, the only thing to do is to replace the origin, I.E. as @moonboots mentioned in the question's comments.